# Returning state of point from postgis / mapnik pgsql db

Tags: postgis, mapnik

I realize that I can confirm whether or not a point lies within a state like this:

```
            SELECT ST_Contains(poly,pt) As testr
            FROM
            (
                    SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-11817883.86 4424094.21)',900913) As pt,
                    (SELECT way FROM planet_osm_polygon WHERE admin_level='4' and name='New Mexico') As poly
            ) As foo;
```

However, I'm looking for a more direct way to find what state a point lies in.

Any suggestions?

---

Taking @Paul's advice, I constructed the following query that worked surprisingly fast:

```
SELECT name
FROM planet_osm_polygon As poly
WHERE admin_level='4' AND ST_Contains(poly.way,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-11820276.11 4441642.75)',900913));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just query the table:

```
SELECT name 
FROM planet_osm_polygon
WHERE admin_level='4'
AND ST_Contains(way, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-11817883.86 4424094.21)',900913));
```